# Resizing middle container

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Any idea on how can I resize the middle red container on window resize, given the 2 black containers with fixed width on left and right? I know I can do this in jQuery calculating window width and apply to the middle `<div>` but I wonder if there's another js-less solution.
[Plnkr link here](http://plnkr.co/edit/15pQKoGQE20FFA93cNNi?p=preview)

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="pull-left black"></div>
  <div class="middle red"></div>
  <div class="pull-right black"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox?

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/w6rqy5wp/)

```css
#wrapper {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
}
.black {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background: #000;
}
.red {
  flex: 1;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have to get into flexbox :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:
Let's say your black container is 50px.

```
.black{
  width: 50px;
}
```

Then your red container is some size - 2*50px. I dont't know what size you want but for this example let's say you need it to be full window width. Then you would do:

```
.red{
  width: calc(100vw - 100px);
}
```

Hope this helps.